# Adding Dynamic Css with EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I created this view

```
{{#view Q.FlashView id="flash-view"}}
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">
    <div id="message" {{bindAttr class=":alert-box :radius"}} data-alert>
      {{view.content.message}}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/view}}
```

with this definition

```
Q.FlashMessage = Ember.Object.extend({
  type: "notice",
  message: null,
  isNotice: (function() {
    return this.get("type") === "notice";
  }).property("type").cacheable(),
  isWarning: (function() {
    return this.get("type") === "warning";
  }).property("type").cacheable(),
  isError: (function() {
    return this.get("type") === "error";
  }).property("type").cacheable(),
  isSuccess: (function() {
    return this.get("type") === "success";
  }).property("type").cacheable()
});

Q.FlashView = Ember.View.extend({
  contentBinding: "Q.FlashController.content",
  classNameBindings: ["isNotice: secondary", "isWarning: alert", "isError: alert", "isSuccess: success"],
  isNoticeBinding: "content.isNotice",
  isWarningBinding: "content.isWarning",
  isErrorBinding: "content.isError",
  isSuccessBinding: "content.isSuccess",
```

What I am trying to do is to make the view display the following css class depending on the type if notice for example to have class="alert-box radius notice".

I can't figure out how is this done, as it seems this classNameBindings is not working out with static content.

I already asked this question to the original author in which I took the code from, [coderberry.me/blog/2013/06/20/using-flash-messages-with-emberjs/](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/06/20/using-flash-messages-with-emberjs/)

you can see the original code there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add dynamic classes either to the Q.FlashView (id="flash-view") or to the message div (id="message") ???

Comment: To the div id="message", I want to add dynamic class with these static classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class based on a property

```
    <div id="message" {{bindAttr class=":alert-box :radius view.isNotice:notice view.isWarning:warning"}} >
     {{view.content.message}}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a syntax error on `classNamesBindings` definition?

```
classNameBindings: ["isNotice: secondary", "isWarning: alert", "isError: alert", "isSuccess: success"],
```

it should look like this (without spaces after the colon):

```
  classNameBindings: ["isNotice:secondary", "isWarning:alert", "isError:alert", "isSuccess:success"],
```

and the `classNameBindings` should work with computed properties. If no you can set up observer to change static property as a walkaround.

Comment: Thanks for the help, apparently my question was little bit confusing the solution of Selva-G down there is correct